# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in vb.net while performing INNER JOIN on two data tables

Tags: vb.net

I was debugging following code and got the exception: 
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'data1.PS NO=data2.PS N'.

code is:

```
        If data1 Is Nothing And data2 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Open two excel files to generate report", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Try Again")
       Else
           cntcn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'"
        oleConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cntcn)

        oleCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT May FROM [data1] INNER JOIN [data2] ON data1.PS NO=data2.PS NO WHERE data1.Month = 'May'", oleConnection)

        oleCommand.Fill(data3)

    End If
```

here I have created two data tables data1 and data2 and applied inner join query.But got the above exception
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a column named "PS NO"?  It is very poor practice to use identifiers with spaces in them so you should remove those spaces.  If you can't or won't do that then you already know what to do because you're already doing it with the table names, i.e. put brackets around the column names so they are treated as a single identifier.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney Yes I have column PS NO.I put it in brackets.But now new error is coming : 'The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'data1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'data1' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.  " but data1 is local object.

Answer (score 0):

```
   oleCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT data1.Month FROM [data1] INNER JOIN [data2] ON data1.[PS NO]=data2.[PS NO] WHERE data1.Month = 'May'", oleConnection)
```

Problems:

1. You have: `SELECT May` change to `data1.[Month]`
2. Change this:  `data1.PS NO` to this:  `data1.[PS NO]`

Comment: Thanks @alwaysVBNET. I modified code as per above suggestion.But still it is comming like: "'The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'data1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'data1' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator. " but my data1 is local object. "

Comment: @Krishna Make sure you have access to that database file. Write a simple select * from data1 to see if you get the same error. If you do, then check if you can read from that file. Are you sure you are passing the database file path to this:  Source={0} ?